# How to continue parser after syntax error

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I use `yy_scan_string` and `yyparse()` to parse some text. I want to continue parse next string when appears syntax error,but it not work.

yacc file snippet:

```
set:SET PARENTHESIS reference EQUAL expression CLOSE_PARENTHESIS {$$ = set_directive($3,$5); }
|error { printf("set error abourt!");YYACCEPT;}//when appears error,I want to continue parsing the next string.I hava used YYABORT,but it not work as I want
;
...

int main(){

 yy_scan_string("#set($b ==9)"); //this string has syntax error.
    yyparse();
    yylex_destroy();
    printf("=====================11111========================\n");

    traverse(snode); //print the ast
    free_tree(snode); // release the memory


    yy_scan_string("#if($r==5) wewqewqe #end"); //this string is right,I want to continue to parse this after paser the string on it: "#set($b ==9)"
    yyparse();
    yylex_destroy();
    printf("=====================222222========================\n");

    traverse(snode);
    free_tree(snode);

    return 1;
}

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}


int yyerror(char* s){
    printf("=====================error %s========================\n",s);
    //reset_input();
    //yyclearin;

    return 0;
}
```

How should I do, please help me!

Answer (score 2):

In error recovering there some principals you should know:

- we should add the `error` token as an alternative to the reduction (done)
- we should tell our parser that the error is ok and we call for that `yyerrok` (not done)
- you can also use the yyclearin to discard current token

  PS; the chronology of execution:

  in error case, yyerror is called the yyerrstate equals 1 after that yyerrok is called it reinitialize the error status at 0 and you can obviously call any macro after that...

  ```
    |error { yyerrok; yyclearin;printf("set error abourt!");}
    ;
  ```

Comment: I do as you said，but program is gridlocked, no continue to run

Comment: exactly this can't be an absolute result to recover the syntactic tree it may be not recoverable, but am not sure that your manner to call yyparse is good, make all your input in test.txt than in your main do yyin = fopen(test.txt); then call yyparse only one time

Comment: I have found the problem,there are tow public variables in lex file: `int bracket_flag = 0;int blank_close_flag = 0;` When encounters an error need to he is set to 0,otherwise the parse a second time would not be expected,thank you very much.